# Pass Templated iterator for STL Container

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

For an exercise for my C++ class (which hasn't covered Boost yet), I am having trouble writing a templated method to accept two iterators for summing numeric values in an STL container.
Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
double Sum(const T & c) {
    return 42.0;    // implementation stubbed
}

// need help writing this method signature to accept two iterators
template<typename T>
double Sum(const typename T::const_iterator & begin,
           const typename T::const_iterator & end) {
    return 43.0;    // another implementation stub
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v;
    v.push_back(3.14);
    v.push_back(2.71);
    v.push_back(1.61);    // sums to 7.46

    std::cout << Sum(v) << ' '              // line 23
              << Sum(v.begin(), v.end())    // line 24
              << '\n';
}
```

I expect this code to output `42 43`, but it fails to compile.
The error g++ gives me is:

```
test_exercise2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_exercise2.cpp:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘Sum(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >)’
```

If I comment out line 24, I get `42` as the output, as expected.
I get the same error message whether or not the second templated method is present or not, so for some reason, it's not able to resolve the call on line 24 to the second method I wrote.

**What signature must I have for the method that accepts two iterators?**

---

The reason why I'm stuck on this is because I need to support summing over the second element of `std::map<K, V>`. This will require two more overloads to call `->second` instead of dereferencing the iterator:
1. `template<typename K, typename V> double Sum(const std::map<K, V> & m);` (I'm okay with this one)
2. and another one involving iterators over the map.

I feel like I'll be able to write the methods for `std::map` if I can figure out how to specify the passing of iterators for `std::list` and `std::map`. I'm okay with solutions that use template-templates.

---

EDIT: The precise wording of problem (omitting non-contributory sentences).
The containers from "the previous exercise" were `std::vector<double>`, `std::list<double>`, `std::map<std::string, double>`.

> Create a template function called Sum() that accepts the template
>   argument T as input and returns a double. The template argument will
>   be a container.
>
> - In the implementation get an iterator (T::const_iterator) for the end. Then create a loop that iterates the container T and adds all
>     values. Finally return the sum.
> - In the main program, call the Sum() function for the different container from the previous exercise.
>
> The Sum() function created calculates the sum of the complete
>   container. Also create a Sum() function that calculates the sum
>   between two iterators. The function then uses the template argument
>   for the iterator type and accepts two iterators, the start and end
>   iterator.

Comment: Do you *need* to provide the specialization for the `Sum` overload that takes the two iterators? Have you been told what SFINAE is? Is the specialization required for a *concrete* type of map? (Hint: you cannot have partial specializations of function templates)

Comment: Aye, the homework specifies the `Sum` overload that takes two iterators. The course did not teach what SFINAE is, but I am happy to learn about it.

Comment: SFINAE is an acronym for Substitution Failure Is Not An Error, which means that if the compiler starts to consider a template as a candidate for overload resolution, but while performing type inference the substitution of the type into the template fails (the substitution is not possible), the template will be discarded, but that will not cause a compilation error. In a more broad sense the term is used to refer to techniques that use that feature of the language to enable/disable templates by forcing a substitution error.

Comment: Going back to your question, you should revisit the requirements. I am not too sure that what you think they are asking and what they are really asking is the same thing. For starters, template functions cannot be partially specialized (only fully specialized, i.e. you can specialize for `std::map<int,double>`, but you cannot specialize for `std::map<T,U>` where `T` and `U` are unbound types. I am not saying that it cannot be done, just that the solution to that is probably beyond the scope of a course if SFINAE has not been explained.

Comment: Oh really? Well, that would have been useful to know. I was actually thinking this was a poor question for other reasons, so I appreciate you pointing me to things I ought to read up on, so I'll go do that. I might post no more than one question relating to this homework in the near future.

Comment: I would recommend that you post the exact requirements. BTW, some of the options that can be taken would include: a) SFINAE by requiring that the iterator's value_type is a `std::pair<>` (which is a property of maps) or b) don't specialize the function but delegate internally to a second templated function that has two overloads, one that returns the input, the other that return `.second` if the argument is a `std::pair`. Neither approach are not *really* a solution to the question, as they don't pinpoint at a `map` iterator, the iterator from `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` would be matched

Comment: I have added the requirements. The delegation method sounds nice actually. I was actually thinking about breaking this out into another question (that would hopefully be posed a bit better on my part).

Comment: There is no specialization in the requirements in the question. The common way to approach this generically would be creating a  `Sum` that takes the containers, and then another `Sum` that takes the iterator and a property-map (borrowing Dietmar Khül's naming: a function that maps from the object to the property you are interested): `template <typename Iterator, typename PMap> double Sum( Iterator first, Iterator last, PMap pmap ) { ... sum += pmap(*first); ... }` That way the algorithm will be generic and can take *any* type for calculations. It is up to the caller to provide the pmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As DeadMG said, the simple way is to template on the type of the iterator. The common convention is, on the other hand, to pass iterators by value:

```
template <typename Iterator>
double Sum( Iterator begin, Iterator end );
```

As to why the original code was not working, the problem is that the type of the container is not deducible:

```
template <typename T>
double Sum( T::const_iterator begin, T::const_iterator end );
Sum( v.begin(), v.end() );        // [*] Assume v == const std::vector<double>&
```

When the compiler tries to infer the type of the arguments to `Sum` it only sees the type returned by `v.begin()` and `v.end()`, which are the *iterator*. From that type, it cannot *guess* the type of the container. To be able to determine what the type `T` is, it would have to test all non template types, and generate all infinite possible instantiations of template types to look whether they have a nested type `const_iterator` that matches the type of `v.begin()` and `v.end()`. Because that would be impossible, to achieve, the language forbids it in the first place.

Beyond that, and related to the comment <sup>[*]</sup>, even if the type would be deducible, overload resolution is performed on the arguments to the function, and not how the expression is later use. In your program, the argument to `.begin()` is a `std::vector<double>` non-const *lvalue*. Because it is not const, the overload selected will yield a non-const iterator (even if in the function you want to call, there is no need to read it).

Answer (score 7):

You're overcomplicating this. You want a pair of iterators of any type? Well, that's just as simple as .. two arguments, of any type.

```
template<typename Iterator>
double Sum(const Iterator& begin,
           const Iterator& end) {
    return 43.0;    // another implementation stub
}
```

Problem solved.

By the way, take a hint from the C++ Standard lib: If you can't de-reference the iterator, make the user provide a function to get the value from the iterator. Don't special-case `std::map` because tomorrow there's `std::unordered_map` and the day after that `boost::multimap` and all sorts of fun. And what if I wanted you to sum the *keys* from the `std::map`, not the values?

Your hardcoded case is a little more complex. A pair of iterators that have to come from `std::map`? Not even sure if possible without explicit template arguments.

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename Comp, typename Alloc>
double Sum(
    const std::map<K, V, Comp, Alloc>& map
) { ... }
```

Notice that I specifically said it had to be a `std::map` instantiation. This allows the compiler to deduce the parameters. From here, you can access the iterators.

Comment: I agree with your solution for vectors and lists (as it was my initial solution). I further agree that the user should provide a predicate to fetch the value for more complicated iterators. Unfortunately ...

Comment: I think you a word there. Or maybe a sentence.

Comment: ... The homework regrettably specifies us to hard-code a special-case for `std::map` to sum over the values. I kinda want to take the hit in points out of sheer defiance. So at this point, it's really just a curiosity for me.

Comment: The attempt at the `map` won't work, as the type is in a non-deducible context.

Comment: Yep, I realized that. Brief brain fart but I changed it, and now the parameters are in a deducible context.

Comment: I apologize DeadMG, you've been awesome for me. The fault's on me for not providing all the info upfront, trying to get the question size down. I have this method already for my `std::map`, though I only template K and V. What I want to know is, can we create a method that accepts two `std::map` iterators templated to handle different key/value types?

Comment: It seems like you had that there, but then edited it out. Is that due to David's comment?

Comment: @Prashant: Yes, the solution that used the two iterators had the same issue that your original code. As I (at least tried to) explained in my answer, you cannot deduce the type `T` out of a nested type (`iterator` or `const_iterator`)

Comment: That is definitely the core of the difficulty I've been having! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: You cannot accept two iterators and deduce the template parameters for the parent map. That's impossible.

Answer (score 5):

The distinguishing feature when contrasting iterators from e.g. `std::list` with iterators from `std::map` is that the latter have a pair type as their `value_type`. That is to say, given `std::map<K, V>` then both `std::map<K, V>::value_type` and `std::iterator_traits<std::map<K, V>::iterator>::value_type` are `std::pair<const K, V>`.

Hence I suggest your `Sum` template accept any iterator, but that it operates not on elements given from the iterator (i.e. `*it`) and instead on a 'view': `element(*it)`. Now you can take care to make sure that `element` 'does the right thing' when faced with a pair.

As a hint, you could declare `Sum` as the following (with a bit of metaprogramming for getting the return type correctly):

```
namespace result_of {

// Second template parameter is an implementation detail
template<
    typename Iterator
    , typename ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
>
struct Sum {
    // general case: sum over the value type directly
    typedef ValueType type;
};

// If an iterator admits an std::pair as its value_type then we end up here
template<typename Iterator, typename Key, typename Value>
struct Sum<Iterator, std::pair<Key, Value> > {
    // special case: sum over the second type of the value
    typedef Value type;
};

} // result_of

template<typename Iterator>
typename result_of::Sum<Iterator>::type Sum(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

Comment: +1 All containers and iterators have `value_type`. The `value_type` of a map will be `std::pair<const K, T>`, but so will the value map of a vector holding a pairs of constant object and any other type. That being said, your answer is the *best* I had got to, but I fear that the requirements are not well stated.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas If someone with a range of pairs asks for a `Sum` of it, then the worst that will happen is that they will get that sum :) More seriously though, `Sum` is already not constrained to be valid only when summing the `value_type` is (even in the non-pair case), so there already are preconditions anyway. Might as well ask that summing on the second type makes some sense, too. Turning those into constraints left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: +1, way cool bit of meta-programming. I'm definitely going to have to gnaw on this and try this out. Thanks for expanding my mind!